# pyvista converting multiple stacked objects into a single voxel grid

Tags: pyvista

I have several 3D (.ply) files, each sit on top of each other (consider them to be geological layers), I want to convert them into a single voxelised representation.

In pyvista I use the following to visualise 2 vector layers as voxels:

```
v = []
colours = ["lightblue", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]
p = pv.Plotter()
# meshes already read into a list using pv.read()
for surface in meshes:
    colour = random.choice(colours)
    voxels = pv.voxelize(surface, density=density)
    voxels["density"] = np.full(voxels.n_cells, random.uniform(0.01, 1.00))
    v.append(voxels)
# for testing perposes, np.vstack did not work to combine all list items, e.g. arr = np.vstack(v)
v_merge = v[0] + v[1]

p.add_mesh_clip_plane(v_merge, assign_to_axis='x', opacity=opacity, scalars="density")
p.show()
return v
```

[image]

As you can see there are issues

1. The two sets of voxels are on different grids so at the interface the voxels overlap.
2. This highlights that there are overlapping voxels, this is inevitable as the vector files have a shared boundary, so once both are on the same grid I'd like to keep the voxels from the top layer and remove from the lower layer.
3. I want to keep the voxels coloured by their layer, this is set in the `add_mesh` stage, I would like to add a scalar value to the voxels outside of a `pv.Plotter()`.

For point 1 I have tried first merging the two vector surfaces, but this results in `Surface is not closed` warning.

Thank you for any help on these points, I'm just getting into pyvista so I jave some learning to do.

Comment: Without a runnable example it's not clear to me what your situation exactly is, and what your expected outcome exactly is. Do you want to somehow force both parts to correspond to the same voxel grid? If not, how do you want to handle partially overlapping voxels?  Point 3. is also unclear to me. You would first have to figure out the cells, then worry about scalars being inherited. When you "tried first merging the two vector surfaces", what exactly did you try to merge and how did you try to do the merge? What resulted in that "warning"? Was it really a warning, or an error?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні yes, I want to convert both 3D closed objects to the same voxel grid. I first had the two vector objects imported into a list. As in the code I simply put `v_merge = v[0] + v[1]` which I doubt is the best way. Perhaps I need to get or set a bounding box for all of the objects (voxels set to null) and then convert in the object to that set voxel grid? point 2 could be resolved by the order of conversion, essentially an `update` which over-rides any existing voxels. Each object has its own number which can be used as the voxel's attribute.